# Compute similarity between elements from a csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, text-mining

Firstly, I am new to R

I am having a dataframe as :

df<-

```
column-1  column-2 column-3 column-4

vf34       bn56     qw34    mn569
vf34       cv34             mn569
           bn56     qw34    asder45
nght       cv34             asder45
vf34       cv34             mn569
```

Now i want to compute the similarity matrix as :

```
Output1:
          vf34  nght  bn56  cv34  qw34   mn569  asder45     
vf34      0     0     1     2     1      3      0
nght      0     0     0     1     0      0      1
bn56      1     0     0     0     2      1      1
cv34      2     1     0     0     0      2      1
qw34      1     0     2     0     0      1      1
mn569     3     0     1     2     1      0      0
asder45   0     1     1     1     1      0      0
```

So, basically it should find all the possible pairs from the dataframe (or csv file) and form a matrix with the number of occurrences.

For ex: first row, sixth column is 3. So that says in the entire data vf34 and mn569 combination has 
occurred 3 times.

Blank values in the data means the data is missing in the orginal data itself.

I am able to do this in python using countvectorizer and then multiplying the obtained matrix with its transpose. However i am new to R. Could any one help me out with this?

```
 and Output2 that i need is:

1  1 3 2 1 0
 and so on for 5 rows.

 This 1; 1; 3; 2; 1; 0 means: 
 (vf34 and bn56); (vf34 and qw34); (vf34 and mn569); (bn56 and qw34); (bn56 and mn569); 
 (qw34 and mn569) combinations that have occurred.
 These values can be obtained from output1 that is given above.
```

I need these values for all the five rows. How to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by a pair? how the 3 value you mention is computed?

Comment: In 1st, 2nd, 5th rows, you can find vf34 and mn569. So the value to be in the matrix has to be 3. Is this clear?

Comment: @akrun: sorry, that was a mistake. I edited it now :)

Comment: yepp..changes made :)

Comment: @Prince `qw34` and `mn569` has `1` combination.  So, why do you have `0`?

Comment: Thanks alot @akrun . I am being crushed between deadlines thats why i am asking direct codes. Will learn R soon. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to get the expected result.  The work flow is:

1. Get the unique elements from the "dataset" (`unique(unlist(df))`)
2. Remove the empty strings (`''`)
3. Create a pairwise combination ("indx") of columns (`combn(1:..)`)
4. `split` the "indx" by the columns of "indx"
5. Subset the "df" (`df[x]`)
6. Remove the empty strings
7. Change the "character"  columns to "factor" class with levels as "Un1"
8. Get the frequency using `table` and sum (`+`) the list elements.
9. The result (`res`) and transpose of the result is summed again to get the lower and upper diagonal elements same.

   ```
   Un <- unique(unlist(df))
   Un1 <- Un[Un!='']
   indx <- combn(1:ncol(df),2)
   res <- Reduce(`+`,lapply(split(indx, col(indx)), function(x) {
               x1 <- df[x]
               x2 <- x1[!(x1[,1]==''|x1[,2]==''),]
               x2[] <- lapply(x2, factor, levels=Un1)
               tbl <- table(x2)}))

    res1 <- res+t(res)
   res1
   #           column.2
   #column.1  vf34 nght bn56 cv34 qw34 mn569 asder45
   # vf34       0    0    1    2    1     3       0
   # nght       0    0    0    1    0     0       1
   # bn56       1    0    0    0    2     1       1
   # cv34       2    1    0    0    0     2       1
   # qw34       1    0    2    0    0     1       1
   # mn569      3    0    1    2    1     0       0
   # asder45    0    1    1    1    1     0       0
   ```

#### Update

Regarding the "output2", it is not very clear as the values are not matching with your expected results (possible typo?)

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) {x1 <- unlist(df[i,])
                        x2 <- x1[x1!='']
                        i1 <- combn(x2,2)
                   diag(res1[i1[1,], i1[2,]])})
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 1 3 2 1 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 3 2

#[[3]]
#[1] 2 1 1

#[[4]]
#[1] 1 1 1

#[[5]]
#[1] 2 3 2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(column.1 = c("vf34", "vf34", "", "nght", "vf34"
), column.2 = c("bn56", "cv34", "bn56", "cv34", "cv34"), column.3 = c("qw34", 
"", "qw34", "", ""), column.4 = c("mn569", "mn569", "asder45", 
"asder45", "mn569")), .Names = c("column.1", "column.2", "column.3", 
"column.4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```